# Restrict product activation for vendors

Tags: magento

I have the extension *Super Simple Multi Vendor Marketplace Free*. This is used for multiple vendors to create products. This works great.

But, when a vendor creates a product, I'd like the products to be deactived. Only the administrator should be able to activate them.

Any hints where the files are located to modify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution for this:

edit the file **app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Status.php**

add this function to get the role id of the user:

```
/**
* get the role id of the logged in user
*/
static function role_id() {
    $username = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getUsername();
    $role_data = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('username',$username)->getFirstItem()->getRole()->getData();
    return $role_data["role_id"];
}
```

modify this function to hide the "enabled" dropdown item from users not in admin group:

```
static public function getOptionArray()
{
    if (self::role_id() == 1) {
        return array(
            self::STATUS_ENABLED    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Enabled'),
            self::STATUS_DISABLED   => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Disabled')
        );
    } else {
        return array(
            self::STATUS_DISABLED   => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Disabled')
        );
    }
}
```

And this one is to remove the "-- Please Select --" stuff:

```
static public function getAllOptions()
{
    if (self::role_id() == 1) {
        $res = array(
            array(
                'value' => '',
                'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('-- Please Select --')
            )
        );
    } else {
        $res = array();
    }
    foreach (self::getOptionArray() as $index => $value) {
        $res[] = array(
           'value' => $index,
           'label' => $value
        );
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Have fun!